# Posting to Facebook Group using the Graph API and Python

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth

I have been looking for documentation on how to post a message to a group wall on Facebook using Python and the Facebook API to no avail or the documentation has not been clear on what permissions i need to have set.

How can i go about this?

This is my current code.

```
from facepy import GraphAPI

graph = GraphAPI(graphApiAccessToken)

graph.post(path = 'groups/GROUPNAME', message='Hello world')
```

Comment: you commented on the wrong thread but thanks heaps you are so awesome!

Comment: Question has been updated 7stud:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28264022/attempting-a-nested-scrape-using-beautifulsoup/28267503

Comment: @7stud, question updated and not deleted anymore check it out :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, try to use the official [Python Facebook Client](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk).

The API for publishing to a group is [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/group/feed#publish).

The rough code will look like:

```
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(oauth_access_token)
groups = graph.get_object("me/groups")
group_id = groups['data'][0]['id'] # we take the ID of the first group
graph.put_object(group_id, "feed", message="from terminal")
```

Comment: I've edited the code. `Resp` was meant to be `groups`.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing right till initializing GraphAPI instance
after that you can post on group like this

graph.post('group_id/feed', message="your message here")

this worked for hope the same for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer Django, you might also give this repo a try: https://github.com/tschellenbach/Django-facebook