# Attempting a Nested Scrape Using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

My code is as follows:

```
<h1><a name="hello">Hello</a></h1>
<div class="colmask">
<div class="box box_1">
<h4><a>My Favorite Number is</a></h4>
<ul><li><a>1</a></li></ul>
<ul><li><a>2</a></li></ul>
<ul><li><a>3</a></li></ul>
<ul><li><a>4</a></li></ul>
</div>
<div class="box box_2">
<h4><a>Your Favorite Number is</a></h4>
<ul><li><a>1</a></li></ul>
<ul><li><a>2</a></li></ul>
<ul><li><a>3</a></li></ul>
<ul><li><a>4</a></li></ul>
</div>
</div>
<h1 name="goodbye"><a>Goodbye</a></h1>
<div class="colmask">
<div class="box box_1">
<h4><a>Their Favorite Number is</a></h4>
<ul><li><a>1</a></li></ul>
<ul><li><a>2</a></li></ul>
<ul><li><a>3</a></li></ul>
<ul><li><a>4</a></li></ul>
</div>
<div class="box box_2">
<h4><a>Our Favorite Number is</a></h4>
<ul><li><a>1</a></li></ul>
<ul><li><a>2</a></li></ul>
<ul><li><a>3</a></li></ul>
<ul><li><a>4</a></li></ul>
</div>
</div>
```

I am not looping the code properly and i don't correctly know how to iterate because i keep grouping all the values together. Can someone lead me on the right track? I try using the `findNext()` , `nextSibling()`, `findAll()` methods but i am failing.

The output i am hoping for is:

```
Hello : My Favorite Number is : 1
Hello : My Favorite Number is : 2
Hello : My Favorite Number is : 3
Hello : My Favorite Number is : 4
Hello : Your Favorite Number is : 1
Hello : Your Favorite Number is : 2
Hello : Your Favorite Number is : 3
Hello : Your Favorite Number is : 4
Goodbye: Their Favorite Number is: 1
Goodbye: Their Favorite Number is: 2
Goodbye: Their Favorite Number is: 3
Goodbye: Their Favorite Number is: 4
Goodbye: Our Favorite Number is: 1
Goodbye: Our Favorite Number is: 2
Goodbye: Our Favorite Number is: 3
Goodbye: Our Favorite Number is: 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were having problems with `nextSibling` it's because your html actually looks like this:

```
<h1><a name="hello">Hello</a></h1>\n #<---newline
<div class="colmask">
```

See the newline after the `</h1>`?  Even though a newline is invisible, it is still considered text, and therefore it becomes a BeautifulSoup element(a NavigableString), and it's considered the `nextSibling` of the `<h1>` tag.

Newlines can also present problems when trying to get, say, the third child of the following `<div>`:

```
<div>
  <div>hello</div>
  <div>world</div>
  <div>goodbye</div>
<div>
```

Here is the numbering of the children:

```
<div>\n #<---newline plus spaces at start of next line = child 0
  <div>hello</div>\n #<--newline plus spaces at start of next line = child 2
  <div>world</div>\n #<--newline plus spaces at start of next line = child 4
  <div>goodbye</div>\n #<--newline = child 6
<div>
```

The divs are actually children numbers 1, 3, and 5.  If you are having trouble parsing html, then 101% of the time it's because the newlines at the end of each line are tripping you up.  The newlines always have to be accounted for and factored into your thinking about where things are located.

To get the `<div>` tag here:

```
<h1><a name="hello">Hello</a></h1>\n #<---newline
<div class="colmask">
```

...you could write:

```
h1.nextSibling.nextSibling
```

But to skip ALL the whitespace between tags, it's easier to use `findNextSibling()`, which allows you to specify the tag name of the next sibling you want to locate:

```
findNextSibling('div')
```

Here is an example:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

with open('data2.txt') as f:
    html = f.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for h1 in soup.findAll('h1'):
    colmask_div = h1.findNextSibling('div')

    for box_div in colmask_div.findAll('div'):
        h4 = box_div.find('h4')

        for ul in box_div.findAll('ul'):
            print'{} : {} : {}'.format(h1.text, h4.text, ul.li.a.text)



--output:--
Hello : My Favorite Number is : 1
Hello : My Favorite Number is : 2
Hello : My Favorite Number is : 3
Hello : My Favorite Number is : 4
Hello : Your Favorite Number is : 1
Hello : Your Favorite Number is : 2
Hello : Your Favorite Number is : 3
Hello : Your Favorite Number is : 4
Goodbye : Their Favorite Number is : 1
Goodbye : Their Favorite Number is : 2
Goodbye : Their Favorite Number is : 3
Goodbye : Their Favorite Number is : 4
Goodbye : Our Favorite Number is : 1
Goodbye : Our Favorite Number is : 2
Goodbye : Our Favorite Number is : 3
Goodbye : Our Favorite Number is : 4
```

Comment: Thankyou. You really helped me understand how BeautifulSoup works.